# Why did the Protector remove the shirt?

Tags: the-protector

In the Turkish Netflix series *The Protector*, the titular character and his predecessors have a magical shirt that grants invincibility. As we see from when Hakan first puts the shirt on, it merges with his body and appears in the form of a raised brand or perhaps a tattoo. As such, there would seem to be no good reason to take it off.

However, we see that when the Protector preceding Hakan was killed, he had taken off his shirt to take a shower, after having killed one of the remaining Immortals. Especially after such a dangerous situation, why would he remove the shirt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It seems that wearing the shirt for too long causes exhaustion.** As one of the previous Protectors explicitly notes in a flashback in Season 2, Episode 1, "it tires you."

Although not explicitly stated, it seems likely that the more the shirt is used (not simply worn), the faster the user tires. As such, that would explain why the Protector directly before Hakan removed the shirt right after killing some Immortals, during a potentially dangerous situation: presumably the shirt had seen a lot of use, and he wanted to relax in the shower.